# I am getting the error "bad operand types for binary operator '+' and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: arrays

This code is going to do the Fibonacci series but with a dynamic array. I am a beginner with programming so if there is anything else wrong with my code, feel free to correct it.

```
public class FibonacciDynamic
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int[] numbers;
       int[] x;
       numbers = new int[x+1]; //This is where bad operand is coming from
       numbers[0]=0;
       numbers[1]=1;
       System.out.println("\n Fibonacci series: \n");
       System.out.println(numbers[0]);
       for (int i=2; i<x+1; i++)
       {
          numbers[i]=numbers[i-2]+numbers[i-1];
          System.out.println(numbers[x]);
       }
   }
}
```

Error -
   bad operand types for binary operator '+'

first type: int[]; second type: int

Comment: The error is caused by trying to add an int array (`x`) and an int (`1`). You probably intent for `x` to be the count of Fibonacci numbers to calculate. If so I'd recommend giving it an appropriate name, like `int fibonacciCount = ...`.  Note that to just print out and then immediately forget the Fibonaccis like you're doing here, you don't really _need_ a `numbers` array at all; you just need three `int`s which store the third, second, and first most-recent of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the two values you are trying to add together are not the same type and java does not understand what it means to add them together. The reason this is happening is because arrays are objects in Java, and all objects live on the Heap (in memory). Therefore, x is not an integer, but rather it is a memory location. Some hexadecimal value like 0xf6434. Java *could* interpret that as an integer, but for type safety it throws an error and forces you to handle it.

So what are you trying to do with this statement: numbers = new int[x+1]?
Are you trying to create an array called numbers that is bigger then the array x by 1? in order for this to work your code should look like this: numbers = new int[x.length+1]; Furthermore, you must initialize x to point to an array with some size. Currently, the variable x is simply a pointer on your call stack which is not pointing towards any object (specifically an array).